# "Who knows what we could find!" -- what would be the difference if "might" were used?

Tags: modal-verbs

Here is a piece of a dialogue from a video game. A group of mages is going to explore some ancient ruins; they seem to be doing this out of interest.

> Elvali: "I can't believe we're doing this."
>   Savos: "Can you imagine the looks on their faces when we come back?"
>   Hafnar: "You keep talking like you're sure we'll find something useful in here."
>   Girduin: "Given the history of this place, it's more than likely there's still some amount of power here."
>   Savos: "Enchanted weapons, tomes of ancient knowledge, Shalidor's secrets themselves — who knows what we **could** find!"

I am not sure I understand what the difference would be between *could* and *might* if the latter were used in that sentence. When I was reading it the first time, I expected *might* to be there, as it would be showing their chance of finding anything in those ruins.

Here is what I found on ELU:

> The difference between *I could go the cinema* and *I might/may go to the cinema* is that the former is associated with reasoning about conditions or alternatives, whereas the latter is just a statement of possibility.
>   <sub>Source: [What is the difference between 'can', 'could', 'may' and 'might'? -- English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/99967)</sub>

---

Now, does *could* in my sentence imply some kind of condition? For example:

> Who knows what we would be able to obtain, or whether we would be interested in whatever we find here.

Whereas *might* would imply:

> Who knows if there is anything in these ruins. There might or might not be anything in them.

---

I also looked up the difference in Swan's *Practical English Usage* (Unit 435). Here is an excerpt:

> **'general' possibility: *can/could*, not *may/might***
>
> We normally use *can* and *could* to say that things are possible in general: people are able to do them, the situation makes them possible, or there is nothing to stop them (see 122). *May* and *might* are not used in this way.
>
> **chances: *may/might/could*, not *can***
>
> To talk about the chance (possibility) that something will happen, or is happening, we use *may*, *might* or *could*, but not *can*.

According to the *chances* section, it seems *might* and *could* can mean the same thing.

Are my suggestions above right, and is there a difference between *might* and *could* in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swan's got the entirety of the definitions correct. "Could" is talking about possibility, emphasizing that things are able to happen, while "might" is talking about probability, emphasizing that things may or may not actually happen.

> Happy optimist: "tomorrow could be amazing! The king could visit and a giant feast could happen, and there could be plenty to eat and people to play with..."
>   Pessimist: "yeah, that might happen. Or it might not. It probably won't."

So Savos seems to me to be really excited about the expedition, and he's already thinking about the things he's expecting to find. Girduin seems more like the kind of person to say "there might be some interesting things down there." Girduin wants to explore, but isn't too caught up in the idea of finding anything of value, just willing to explore for the possibility.

Comment: Do you mean Hafnar instead of Girduin? (_You keep talking like you're sure_...)

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I'm not saying Girduin is a pessimist, Hafnar is a pessimist. But Girduin is somewhere in the middle, someone who would focus on the probability. Hafnar is like "this is ridiculous, there's no way we'll find anything in here." Girduin "we might..." Savos "we could find all sorts of things!"